# Verifying speed of waves in solid material

Tags: experimental-physics

[image: Example-Image]

In an experiment, a steel ball is dropped on an aluminium plate and the voltage response and time are recorded through an oscilloscope. I am trying to verify the speed of sound in the material through mathematical calculations.

I know the location of impact of the steel ball. With these co-ordinates, I can calculate the distance between a reference point and the location of impact, using 'distance formula'. I get the time difference between the impact and reference point through oscilloscope. So now I know the distance and time and by distance/time, I should get the speed of waves in the material. The representation can be seen in the image link, where the x and y axis are both in mm, representing the length and width of the plate.

But this value that I get is different from the material speed for aluminium. Does anyone know why that would be? I saw an explanation [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238209/measuring-speed-of-sound-in-a-solid-specimen) and I don't exactly know if not having a high enough amplitude and frequency is the reason that I am not getting the right answer?

Comment: I wonder what the difference is between using a standing wave and any wave.

Comment: I am guessing it might be to maintain the same amplitude. But don't exactly know how it would affect the results.

Comment: I'm wondering if the reason is the grain of your plate since it's probably rolled. One axis almost matches but the other does not. I'm just as in the dark as you but I would try your setup on a metal rod. and measure the time difference between the signal between two detectors positioned down the rod.

Comment: I could use as many guesses as possible to move forward. I did not understand what you meant by the axes matching? To what are they matching/not matching? Actually the real experiment was to be done on an aluminised PVDF (polyvinlydiene diflouride) foil by attaching it to a frame and pasting four PVDF sensors at the corner in a diagonal manner. But I could not verify experimentally the speed of waves in aluminised PVDF which ranges from 1590 - 1900 m/s in various literature. I am getting values way smaller like in 1. something. I have checked the units many times as well.

Comment: You know how wood has a grain direction? Metal does too if it is forged, extruded, or rolled. You can also drop the ball in different locations to see if the speed is repeatable on the same axis.

Comment: Ok, that is a good suggestion. Will keep in mind !